# strange misalignment between divs container due to internal font-size elements

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a little problem, probably trivial, that I can't really solve. I've two `div`'s, each containing a `div` with some text inside.
I noticed that changing the font height within those two inner containers, misaligns the outer ones. I know i could probably play with `absolute` positions, but can someone tell me why?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outBox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(173, 247, 136);
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inBox {
  width: 120px;
  background: rgba(53, 186, 222, 1);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inBox h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.inBox p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outBox">
  <div class="inBox">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outBox">
  <div class="inBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone will come along who can explain why inline-flex on an element differs to flex on the parent (I don't fully understand it), but I do know that if you take off the "display: inline-flex" on your outBox, and put them inside a container element with "display: flex" (or put that on the body), it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you (both) it solved the actual problem. But can i ask you why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the divs in a "wrapper" with it display set to "flex"

```
.wrapper {
```

display: flex;
}

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
      }
 
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  
}
      .outBox {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background: rgb(173, 247, 136);
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;

      }

      .inBox {
        width: 120px;
        background: rgba(53, 186, 222, 1);
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .inBox h2 {
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 16px;
        
        color: white;

      }

      .inBox p {
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="outBox">

  <div class="inBox">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="outBox">

  <div class="inBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

</div>
  
</div>
```